# Why are inner class not public when viewed in reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

AKA why does this test fail?

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void InnerClassShouldBePublic()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(typeof (InnerClass).IsPublic);
    }

    public class InnerClass
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It fails because nested types are not considered [Public](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.ispublic.aspx), they are considered [`NestedPublic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isnestedpublic.aspx) instead.

From the [`IsPublic()` MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.ispublic.aspx):

> Do not use with nested types; use [`IsNestedPublic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isnestedpublic.aspx) instead.

Comment: A related property is `IsVisible`. It returns true if the class (or struct, interface, enum, delegate type) is public and all outer (containing) types are also public. So for non-nested classes it's like `IsPublic`, and for nested types it's like `IsNestedPublic` combined with `IsNestedPublic` for all outer classes, and `IsPublic` for the outermost class.

Comment: Note that a `protected` class which sits inside a `public` class is also "visible" in a sense, even if the `IsVisible` property I mentioned before returns false. Example: [`TypeConverter+SimplePropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.simplepropertydescriptor.aspx)